# Why do items match in Fuse.js if the pattern contians a letter that doesn't exist in those items?

Tags: javascript, fuzzy-search

I am currently evaluating Fuse.js to filter a list of elements and obtain their match positions for highlighting purposes. However I noticed that Fuse.js returns items that I did not expect in the first place. For instance given the list `["data_snacks"]` and the pattern `dtaeg` it still matches, albeit with a high score.

My expectations were the following:

- The characters in the pattern MUST appear in the same order. In RegEx terms `(.*)d(.*)t(.*)a(.*)e(.*)g(.*)`.
- Similarly all characters in the pattern MUST occur, in the example the word should not match as it does not contain a G.

Do the options allow to make the search more exact in nature rather than "too fuzzy"?

Comment: Fuse.js uses [Levenshtein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) to perform matching. Technically, everything is a match but the scores vary based on how many characters need to be added or removed in order to make the match work. Fuse.js has some other [match types](https://fusejs.io/examples.html#extended-search) but none of them meet your requirements.

Comment: For what it's worth I stumbled upon the fuzzysort package that does the trick: https://www.npmjs.com/package/fuzzysort
Personally speaking, fuzzy search should never allow transpose or delete like Fuse.js does. It feels odd, especially coming from multiple IDEs that don't behave like this.